# No Response on NGINX when using upstream

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http, proxypass

I'm trying to load balance a web application through nginx, It works fine for all will my web application calls a service with sub-path.

for example it works

```
http://example.com/luna/
```

but not for

```
 http://example.com/luna/sales
```

My nginx.conf

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

     map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    upstream lunaups {
        server myhostserver1.com:8080;
        server myhostserver2.com:8080;
    }


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.com;

        proxy_pass_header Server;

        location = / {
             rewrite ^ http://example.com/luna redirect;
         }

        location /luna {
            rewrite ^$/luna/(.*)/^ /$1 redirect;
            proxy_pass http://lunaups;
            #add_header  X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

my web application calls a service with additional subpath like /luna/sales fails to return response. What am i missing here?

It works if i remove one of my host server from upstream, But when I add second host on upstream it fails to return response.

Is my rewrite rule wrong or my configurations as whole is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule redirects the web browser from `/luna/sales` to `/sales`. This means the web browser does a new HTTP request for `/sales`, but then you have no `location` block that matches `/sales` so you get a 404 error.

I believe what you really are trying to do is changing the URI that is proxied to the upstream. If so, you could try changing your `location` block:

```
location ~ /luna(?<upstream_uri>(/.*)?) {
    proxy_pass http://lunaups/$upstream_uri;
}
```

This will match either `/luna` or `/luna/whatever`, bind the matched subexpression as `$upstream_uri` and then send only that subexpression to your upstream.

Comment: Hi Emil, It won't work. I'm Using Jetty as backend webserver.My web application as whole runs on /luna, but on my webpage(e.g "about" page) a request is triggered(e.g luna/about/) but it wont get any response. On browser my path is still /luna.